# mysql datetime data to the html5 datetime-local field using javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, datetime

I want to replace data of HTML5 'datetime-local' field value with the 'MySQL datetime' value using PHP and JavaScript. But I tried many things it dint worked. Here is my code:

**HTML Code:**

```
Dispatch Date : <input type="datetime-local" id="dispatch_date" name="dispatch_date"/>
```

**PHP and Javascript Code:**

PHP:

```
$qry="select * from table_name ORDER BY p_rec_date DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($result)

$test_date2=date('d-m-Y g.i a', strtotime($res[9]));
$test_date=str_replace(" ", "_", $test_date2);

echo"<a id='".$res[0]."' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=vpb_show_login_box(this.id,'".$test_date."');>".$res[0]."</a>";
```

JavaScript:

```
function vpb_show_login_box(id1,id2)
   {
      var replaced = id2.replace(/[_]/g,' ');
      document.getElementById("dispatch_date").value = replaced;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html#input.datetime.attrs.value) the date must be in RFC3339 format:

```
<?php
$qry="select * from table_name ORDER BY p_rec_date DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$date = date(DATE_RFC3339, strtotime($res[9]));
?><input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. The string I fetched from database is "2014-11-11T00:00:00+09:00".

Comment: What MySQL version was that?